# Wrong reputation calculation for the user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I came across this question:

[Move database from SQL Server 2012 to 2008](https://superuser.com/questions/468578/move-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008)

The accepted answer has 33 votes but the answerer's reputation is 84. he also has some other accepted answers with upvotes.

Comment: why did you downvote? in't it so?

Comment: Why do you think it is a bug? Did you look at their profile? Did you check the reputation tab there to see where/why they lost reputation?

Comment: well I didn't thought of the bounties. I thought he must have 1+ 33 * 10 + 15 = 346 reps at least. sorry.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani they even could have reached the daily rep limit (200) if all upvotes were on the same day.

Comment: yes. of course daily rep would be 200. but can make the calculation wrong

Comment: Point being - before *assuming* the reputation calculation is wrong, at least take a look a the profile to see the reputation history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user in question has 500 reputation given away in bounties, as can be seen in their [reputation tab](https://superuser.com/users/100185/rich?tab=reputation).